# Passing values between Entity View and Page View

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

Other than using `Session Attributes` is there a way to pass values from an `Entity View` to `Page View` when using DXA Java? This is with reference to DXA 1.x (actually 1.0 or pre-release version of DXA Java) and SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

We have tried using `cookies` and `request scope attributes` for passing info from `Entity View` to `Page View`, but since everything is within the same request/response flow neither approach seemed to work.

**To give a better picture, this is the use case:**

I have a SDL DXA Page with its corresponding `Controller`, `EntityView` and `PageView`. The purpose of this page is to receive a `QueryString` parameter that identifies the type of image. Based on the type of image being requested, the Controller fetches a random image of this type from a pool of images managed in SDL.

The `Entity View` gets the URL (and physical path) to the image file and it passes it to the `Page View`. The `Page View` then reads the image file from the file system and outputs a binary stream in response, effectively serving the image.

The URL of this page is used as the `src` attribute of an Image used in an email template. So depending on the type of email (registration confirmation, reminder, thank you, etc.) a different image is loaded dynamically on request. Each time the same email is re-opened the user may see a different image (picked from the pool of same type of images).

Currently we are passing the `image path` as a `Session Attribute` from the `Entity View` to the `Page View`, however sometimes the `Page View` is unable to get the `Session Attribute` value resulting in an error and no image being returned.

So we are looking for an alternate way of passing the image URL from the `Entity View` to the `Page View`.

Comment: Maybe you can **edit** your question and specify why `Session Attributes` is not working for you and what other way you are looking for and why?

Comment: @BartKoopman I have tried to explain the use case and current problem we are facing to the best I could. I hope someone can suggest a better way of achieving what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you determine the image path in an Entity View, but not let the Entity View render the image?  It is quite common to use an Entity Model/View/Controller as a kind of widget which dynamically selects items, but normally the Entity View then takes care of rendering those items too (it might delegate rendering to other Entity Views).

Comment: On re-reading I see that you are abusing a Page View to serve an image. It’s a bit dubious design, by why would you even use an Entity View at all in this case? Your Page View can access the Entity Model directly if needed.

Comment: @RickPannekoek thanks for responding. Isn't DXA doing something similar to serve all images in general? If not how are images/css/js resources served by DXA since these are not published or store onto the filesystem directly by the deployer?

What would be the optimal approach to serve images?

Comment: DXA uses an HTTP module to serve static content items (incl. images) instead of a Page Controller/View. See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Statics/StaticContentModule.cs

Comment: Thanks @RickPannekoek. Could you please share an example (or refer me to one) of a Page View accessing Entity Model?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using a Page Model/View/Controller to serve images is abuse of these concepts. DXA serves images (or *static content items* in general) using a [`StaticContentInterceptor`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.7/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common) instead of a Model/View/Controller.
2. You can do without Entity View (because the Entity Model is not really rendered anyways); Entity Models are integral part of the Page Model an can be accessed directly in the Page View: `pageModel.getRegions().get("Main").getEntities().get(0)`